# How to debug kernel hang on osx

Tags: macos, kernel, freeze

I have installed one kernel extension, after which sometimes machine hangs. Not easily reproducible. I have got the kernel dump from my customer which he  generated by generating NMI after hang. Now how should I analyse this core file to find which thread caused hang?

I am new to kernel programming. Any suggestion would be of help. Thanks.